# Email phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estou criando um formulário que quando preenchido envia um email de confirmação, até ai tudo bem, mas eu queria que ele também mandasse um email para mim com os dados preenchidos no formulário,o cliente quer que essas informações vão para o email dele, estou usando o phpmailer, segue abaixo meu código

```
/* Recuperar os Dados do Formulário de Envio*/
$client = $_POST["client"];
$clientIn = $_POST["clientIn"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telComercial = $_POST["comercial"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$whats = $_POST["whats"];


/* Extender a classe do phpmailer para envio do email*/
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");


function smtpmailer($para, $de, $nomeDestinatario, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    /* Montando o Email*/
    $mail->IsSMTP();            /* Ativar SMTP*/
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       /* Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas*/
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     /* Autenticação ativada */
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  /* TLS REQUERIDO pelo GMail*/
    $mail->Host = 'xxxxxx'; /* SMTP utilizado*/
    $mail->Port = 465;             /* A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor*/
    $mail->Username = 'xxx@xxxx.com.br';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxx';
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $nomeDestinatario);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

/* Função Responsável por Enviar o Email*/
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = "<font color='red'><b>Mail error: </b></font>".$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
$error = "<font color='blue'><b>Mensagem enviada com Sucesso!</b> 
</font>";
    return true;
}
}

/* Passagem dos parametros: email do Destinatário, email do remetende, nome do remetente, assunto, mensagem do email.*/
 if (smtpmailer($email, 'xxxx', "xxx","xxx", $corpoMensagem)) {
     Header("location: sucesso.php"); // Redireciona para uma página de Sucesso.
}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
```

Comment: Não bastaria definir a cópia CC?

Comment: `$mail->AddCC('ciclano@site.net', 'Ciclano'); // Copia ` e `//$mail->AddBCC('fulano@dominio.com.br', 'Fulano da Silva'); // Cópia Oculta` Testa ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria você usar "cópia oculta". Não teria porque criar outro objeto para enviar uma "cópia" para você.

---

## Utilizando "para/cc/cco" no PHPMailer:

Para adicionar destinatários ("**para**"), use `$mail->AddAddress()`:

```
$mail->AddAddress('pessoaA@dominio.com', 'Pessoa A');
$mail->AddAddress('pessoaB@dominio.com', 'Pessoa B');
...
```

Para adicionar "com cópia" ("**cc**"), use `$mail->AddCC()`:

```
$mail->AddCC('pessoaC@dominio.com', 'Pessoa C');
$mail->AddCC('pessoaD@dominio.com', 'Pessoa D');
...
```

Para adicionar "com cópia oculta" ("**cco**"), use `$mail->AddBCC()`:

```
$mail->AddBCC('pessoaE@dominio.com', 'Pessoa E');
$mail->AddBCC('pessoaF@dominio.com', 'Pessoa F');
...
```

---

Você pode usar todos juntos ou, somente uma opção ou outra.

---

**PS**.: *Não é obrigatório o "nome" do destinatário*.

Exemplo:

```
$mail->AddBCC('pessoaG@dominio.com');
```

---

Na parte "**A Simple Example**" da **documentação**, você pode ver que constam os formatos:

```
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
```

Fonte: [Documentação PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) (v.6.0.5)